# readRDS error: bad restore file magic number

Tags: r

I used:

```
saveRDS(res, file = paste(dataPath,'result.rds',sep = '/'))
readRDS(paste(dataPath,"result.rds",sep = "/"))
```

But the error shows:

> Error in load("/Users/Desktop/result.rds") :  bad restore file magic
> number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded In addition: Warning
> messages: 1: In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :   truncating
> string with embedded nuls 2: file ‘result.rds’ has magic number 'X'
> Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated

My r version is `4.1.1`, and RStudio version is `2021.09.0 Build 351`.

Comment: Can you please post your error message as text rather than as an image?

Comment: @BenBolker I just edit it, thank you

Comment: I can't replicate this. If I run `dataPath <- "."; res <- 1:5` and then run your code exactly as written above, it works. Can you try this from a clean R session, and give the results of `sessionInfo`? (Your RStudio version *should* be irrelevant ...)

Comment: @Ben Bolker I tried this in a clear R session, and I can see the result by using readRDS, but when I open the rds file that I saved from desktop, the r just showed the error again.

Comment: It's going to be really hard to reproduce this.  Are you 100% sure that you used `saveRDS()` and didn't accidentally use `save()` when you saved it in the first place?  If you `load()` the file does R complain?

Comment: yes, i use saveRDS(), and my magic number is X instead of RDX..

Comment: What is `res`? Perhaps you are generating a non-standard R object that uses the ALTREP system and has a bug in its serializer.